# number of permutations in which no two consecutive numbers are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the natural numbers from 1 to 10 be arranged so that no two consecutive numbers are adjacent to each other, and how is the formula arrived at?

Comment: Should the consecutive numbers be ordered ? I.e. the arrangement can not have $\ldots, 2, 3, \ldots$, but can it have $\ldots, 3, 2, \ldots$ ?

Comment: @Sasha : no, it can't have ...,3,2,...

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1822068/424260.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is OEIS sequence [A002464](https://oeis.org/A002464). The value for $n=10$ is $479306$; the entry gives several formulas for calculating the terms. It also refers to p. 373 of *Analytical Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick, which you can download [here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html); that page gives a derivation of the ordinary generating function of the sequence.

Comment: Beat me to it, good job.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and references