# Circle permutation without consecutive integers placed together

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

How many ways can $n$ numbers from 1 to $n$ be arranged in a circular order without consecutive integers being placed together? (Note: 1 and $n$ are also considered consecutive integers)

For example, if $n=5$, there are 2 ways: 53142 and 24135 (in a circle); and if $n=6$, I get 6 ways: 531462 and 264135, 241536 and 635142, 631524 and 425136 (in a circle).

I have tried inclusion-exclusion principle but I have found it's difficult to get the expression; and have also failed to get its recursive equation. Any help in this matter will be appreciated!

Comment: If we have an expression for the number of ways that $n$ numbers from 1 to $n$ can be arranged in a **linear** order without consecutive integers being placed together (with $1,n$ considered consecutive integers), then we can answer this question by seeing what happens to a circular arrangement after we remove the largest number and lay the rest out linearly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many permutations of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ there are with no 2 consecutive numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822068/how-many-permutations-of-1-2-3-n-there-are-with-no-2-consecutive-numbe)

Comment: @Rick that's a useful link, but it's not quite the same: we want circular arrangements, and we want to consider $1,n$ to be a "consecutive" pair.

Comment: This [OEIS link](https://oeis.org/A002464) has a lot of information about the linear version of the problem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - I am not sure how to follow up on your first suggestion.  We cut up the circle by removing $n$, leaving a linear array, and the original circle is valid iff (1) the array is itself valid, and (2) the two ends of the array must not contain $1$ nor $n-1$.  While (1) is a solved problem, no quick (symmetry?) approach occurs to me on how do deal with condition (2)...

Comment: Possible approach: I think you can set up a recurrence similar to [Marko Reidel's answer to this question quoted by Rick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1822542/546005).  A symmetry argument may come in handy: among all circles with one violation, exactly $1/n$ of them would have the violation be any specific violation (e.g. $1$ and $n$ being adjacent, or, $1$ and $2$ being adjacent, etc), based on symmetry.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Also, in that question "consecutive" seems to imply in ascending order, whereas here it doesn't.