# Probability of Arranging Books

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability of arranging $6$ different books on a shelf with that no two books get next to each other.

I know the general probability of arranging $6$ books is $6!=720$
with two books get next to each other, I will consider them as one bundle $2!$
but I'm stuck here I don't know how to conclude this.

Edit: How many arrangements are possible of 6 books on shelf with no two adjacent books.
What I got so far is we should treat the two books as one book leaving us with 5 books, so $5!=120$

And these two books can be interchanged so $5!$2!=240$

So the answer will be $6!- $5!$2! = 480$

Comment: What does it mean to say that no two books "get next to each other"?

Comment: if we have 6 books, A  B C D E F, we cannot repeat arranging books with A B next to each other (only one time)

Comment: Depending what else is on that shelf (and more generally, what's your definition of "next to").

Comment: So, you mean you want to avoid the blocks $AB$ and $BA$?  Ok. Well, there are $5!$ arrangements containing $AB$ and $5!$ that contain $BA$ so...

Comment: It's impossible to arrange six books on a shelf so that no two books are adjacent unless you have five dividers to place between books.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking:  in how many ways can you arrange the letters $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ such that $A$ and $B$ are not next to each other.  In any case, the question should be edited to clarify.

Comment: I dont know how to explain the question, how many way we can arrange 6 books, lets name them A, B, C, D, E. 
one way to do this is ABCDE, now we cannot consider any other way having AB or BC or CD or DE

Comment: Ok, I guess I have no idea what you are asking.   Can you give us an example of an acceptable arrangement of $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$? An unacceptable one?   If you can't give examples...well, maybe the question just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'll throw out one last guess:  are you talking about something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96718/number-of-permutations-in-which-no-two-consecutive-numbers-are-adjacent)?  If so, I'd say the answer to that question provides a lot of information.

Comment: ABCDEF , ACBFED these are acceptable, but now this ABCDFE no acceptable. Consider the questions is like this How many arrangements are possible of all of the letters of ABCDEF with no two adjacent letters?

Comment: @ lulu, yes exactly like that question

Comment: Ok, well then you have your answer.  It is associated to the problem of placing non-attacking kings on checkerboards...the solution for $n$ books is given by the [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A002464).