# How many number string with absolute difference of every neighboring digits greater than 1

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

You are given a string with length 10. Its characters are 0,1,2,...,9 (every number are in the string). How many permutations of the string such that the absolute difference of every two neighboring number are greater than 1?

ex:
1425379680 is correct
1234567890 is wrong because 1 and 2's difference are 1, 2 and 3's difference are 1, etc.

Note:
Because it is a string, 0 as a starting number is okay.

*Sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: You should also confirm that $0,9$ are not consecutive in your rule (sometimes for problems like this, the numbers are treated as if they were$\pmod {10}$ integers).

Comment: @RossMillikan I already tried to think the reccurence relation, but I didn't get any idea about how to make the reccurence, because every digits in the string are exactly one.. I can only make it if the number of digits isn't exactly one..

Comment: Do the recursion this way:  Given $n$ let $a_n$ be the number of "good" permutations of the integers $\{0, \cdots, n\}$.  Now get a recursion for the $a_n$.

Comment: @lulu:  we are both thinking of sequences that could contain duplicate numbers, but OP is asking for a permutation of the ten digits.

Comment: @RossMillikan  My proposed recursion scheme is for permutations of the first $n$ integers, with no duplicates.  The idea for the recursion is to consider ways to place the $n$ given an element of $a_{n-1}$ (or a permutation of the $n-1$ with only one bad pair).  I'm sure it's a duplicate question...I'll check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many permutations of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ there are with no 2 consecutive numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822068/how-many-permutations-of-1-2-3-n-there-are-with-no-2-consecutive-numbe)

Comment: @lulu: I don't think it does as 321 is not a consecutive sequence.

Comment: @SharodSaor  Oh, does that question require that the consecutive numbers be in the correct order?  If so, then I agree it is not a duplicate.  Let me read it more carefully.

Comment: @SharodSaor  Yes, you are right. I'll withdraw the duplicate close vote.  Though, of course, the techniques used in the other problem are clearly relevant here.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96718/number-of-permutations-in-which-no-two-consecutive-numbers-are-adjacent) is an exact duplicate, though the answer just gives a reference to an OEIS page which contains relevant formulas.

Comment: thank you everyone..